# Powershell: Get-Mailbox, split multi-value GrantSendOnBehalfTo to its' own line

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

I'm trying to run a report on users with 'Send on Behalf Of' rights to mailboxes. The results are fine if there's only a single account, but when there're multiples, the values are joined into a single string with default delimiter being spaces. Even when I use split with line-feed as delimiter, it's still treated as a single string separated by line-feed. Here's my current code:

```
get-mailbox "Sales Dept" | select identity,displayname,@{l='SendOnBehalfOf';e={$_.GrantSendOnBehalfTo -join "`n"}}
```

Whether I use split or join, I keep getting variations of this ouput:

```
Identity            Displayname         SendOnBehalfOf
domain\Sales Dept   Sales Dept          User1
                                        User2
                                        User3
                                        User4
```

But what I need is for each User be on their own line like this:

```
Identity            Displayname         SendOnBehalfOf
domain\Sales Dept   Sales Dept          User1
domain\Sales Dept   Sales Dept          User2
domain\Sales Dept   Sales Dept          User3
domain\Sales Dept   Sales Dept          User4
```

How do I get that?

Answer (score 2):

Since your `SendOnBehalfOf` property has the most entries, it is the one you want to iterate over:

```
#Requires -Version 4
Get-MailBox 'Sales Dept' -PipelineVariable 'Sales' |
    ForEach-Object -MemberName 'GrantSendOnBehalfTo' |
    Select-Object -Property @(
        @{N = 'Identity';       E = { $Sales.Identity }}
        @{N = 'DisplayName';    E = { $Sales.DisplayName }}
        @{N = 'SendOnBehalfOf'; E = { $_ }}
    )
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'PipelineVariable'." error. I checked my powershell version and it's 5.1...But how do I check what version I have of the Exchange cmdlets (google just tells me how to find powershell version or Exchange server version, but not Exchange powershell cmdlets :( )

Comment: @Namuna That's a shame that cmdlet doesn't implement a standard parameter.  I don't have an exchange server to run tests on.  Use `(Get-Module -Name 'Exchangemodulename').Version`