# Returning Unique user Id in GrantSendOnBehalfTo attribute in the Get-Mailbox cmdlet

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I'm pulling out details for Delegate details of mailboxes from Office 365 setup using the exchange shell.
The problem is I'm getting the Display name of users in the GrantSendOnBehalfTo attribute of the Mailbox which isn't unique a value. How to print the unique ID of users in the GrantSendOnBehalfTo attribute?
[image]

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49496237/powershell-get-mailbox-split-multi-value-grantsendonbehalfto-to-its-own-line)?

Comment: Did you try this cmdlet: “ Set-Mailbox <Identity>  -GrantSendOnBehalfTo  <Identity> ” ?

For more information, Please refer to this link: https://o365info.com/mailbox-permissions-powershell-commands/

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test this right now, but I think this may help:

```
$SendOnBehalf = Get-Mailbox -Identity 'testing' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty GrantSendOnBehalfTo
foreach ($user in $SendOnBehalf) {
    try {
        # get the user or group that has SendOnBehalf permissions
        $sob = Get-User -Identity $user -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if ($sob) {
            Write-Host "User: $($sob.SamAccountName)"  # or use $($sob.WindowsEmailAddress) if that is more unique for you
        }
        else {
            $sobGroup = Get-Group -Identity $user -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            Write-Host "Group: $($sob.SamAccountName)"
        }
    }
    catch {}
}
```